# Any difference between dplyr::across and purrr::modify_if/at?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

If one wanted to apply a function to one or more columns, optionally based on some criteria, it seems that there are two identical ways to do this with Tidyverse packages. I'm wondering if there's any reason to prefer one over the other?

For example, if one wanted to convert all numeric columns to character, you could do either of the following:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

mpg |> 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), as.character)) |> 
  slice_head(n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 11
#>   manufacturer model displ year  cyl   trans      drv   cty   hwy   fl    class 
#>   <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 audi         a4    1.8   1999  4     auto(l5)   f     18    29    p     compa…
#> 2 audi         a4    1.8   1999  4     manual(m5) f     21    29    p     compa…
#> 3 audi         a4    2     2008  4     manual(m6) f     20    31    p     compa…
#> 4 audi         a4    2     2008  4     auto(av)   f     21    30    p     compa…
#> 5 audi         a4    2.8   1999  6     auto(l5)   f     16    26    p     compa…

mpg |> 
  modify_if(is.numeric, as.character) |> 
  slice_head(n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 11
#>   manufacturer model displ year  cyl   trans      drv   cty   hwy   fl    class 
#>   <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 audi         a4    1.8   1999  4     auto(l5)   f     18    29    p     compa…
#> 2 audi         a4    1.8   1999  4     manual(m5) f     21    29    p     compa…
#> 3 audi         a4    2     2008  4     manual(m6) f     20    31    p     compa…
#> 4 audi         a4    2     2008  4     auto(av)   f     21    30    p     compa…
#> 5 audi         a4    2.8   1999  6     auto(l5)   f     16    26    p     compa…
```

Or, if you just wanted to change the year column, either of the following would work:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

mpg |> 
  mutate(year = as.character(year)) |> 
  slice_head(n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 11
#>   manufacturer model displ year    cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class 
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8 1999      4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compa…
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8 1999      4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compa…
#> 3 audi         a4      2   2008      4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compa…
#> 4 audi         a4      2   2008      4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compa…
#> 5 audi         a4      2.8 1999      6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compa…

mpg |> 
  modify_at('year', as.character) |> 
  slice_head(n = 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 11
#>   manufacturer model displ year    cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class 
#>   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 audi         a4      1.8 1999      4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compa…
#> 2 audi         a4      1.8 1999      4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compa…
#> 3 audi         a4      2   2008      4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compa…
#> 4 audi         a4      2   2008      4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compa…
#> 5 audi         a4      2.8 1999      6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compa…
```

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other, other than possibly not having to have the extra import of purrr? Or are these identical?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain this is the only difference, but `mutate` only operates on `data.frame`, whereas `modify_if` can operate on `list`s as well.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list(a=1, b="b") %>% modify_if(is.numeric, `+`, 1)
# $a
# [1] 2
# $b
# [1] "b"

list(a=1, b="b") %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . + 1))
# Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
#   no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "list"
```

While you have shown that both, given input that inherits `data.frame`, should produce the same output.

```r
identical(
  iris %>% modify_if(is.numeric, `+`, 1),
  iris %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . + 1))
)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Interestingly, though, `modify_if` is *much* faster:

```r
bench::mark(
  purrr = iris %>% modify_if(is.numeric, `+`, 1),
  dplyr = iris %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . + 1))
)
# # A tibble: 2 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result         memory              time   gc    
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>         <list>              <list> <list>
# 1 purrr         220us  254.5us     3816.    4.88KB     2.65  1440     1      377ms <df [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem [4 x 3]>  <benc~ <tibb~
# 2 dplyr        1.58ms   1.91ms      515.   11.34KB     2.50   206     1      400ms <df [150 x 5]> <Rprofmem [19 x 3]> <benc~ <tibb~
```

[image: bench::mark autoplot]

Comment: Interesting! So it seems that if you're doing a simple transformation, i.e., changing data types, it's better to stick with `modify`.

Comment: I don't think I understand the internals enough to know for certain why there is such a stark speed difference, but it seems reasonable to infer that `across` and `where` might add a little bit of time, and the generality of `mutate` as well. I don't think this benchmark will change my workflow, though: I'll likely stick with `mutate` in dplyr flow, and use `data.table` when speed or size dictate its use.